# Is " in two to five days" a correct experession?

Tags: grammar

I am wondering if "in two to five days" is correct or not. If it is correct, what are the differences among the following expressions? How do you differentiate them? I am Japanese, and the Japanese counterpart of the expression is "2日から5日のうちに.”

1. within two to five days
2. between two to five days

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Hi, Thomas, うち could mean both inside and within (or in). Without context where the phrase would be used, it is not easy to answer your question. Are you talking about a deadline by which something should be done? Based on your Japanese, you seem to mean that. Please clarify with an example sentence.

Answer (score 1):

"In two to five days" is correct English usage in a sentence such as this:

> "Your item will ship in two to five days."

Likewise,

> "Your items will ship within two to five days after receiving your order."

In the above examples, "between two to five days" would be a bit awkward and not as idiomatic, as the preposition "between" is usually used to describe a relationship between two things or persons; e. g., "That comment was meant to stay between you and me."

However, "between" can be used correctly in the right context; e. g.,

> "Due to changes in the agenda, the meeting could last anywhere between two *and* five days."